# Checking the name and value of an XML node, using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I have a C# application where I need to parse XML using LINQ. This is my first LINQ experience that’s why I am struggling with basic operations

My XML looks something similar to:

```
<Main>
  <Data>
     <NodeTypeA>
        <ElementA>23</ElementA>
        <ElementB>24</ElementB>
     </NodeTypeA>
  </Data>
</Main>
```

So first I want to check the name of the first child of “Data”. In this case it is “NodeTypeA”.

Second I want to read the value of ElementA value. In this example it is “23”

Comment: Is the name `NodaTypeA` meaningful, or do you only want the value of `ElementA`?

Comment: yes its meaningful. If, for eg, the node name is NodeTypeB then i have to do some other activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
var firstElement = xml.Descendants("Data").Elements().FirstOrDefault();
if (firstElement != null && firstElement.Name == "NodeTypeA")
{
    var elementAValue = (string)firstElement.Element("ElementA");
}
```